# meteor - unexpected token error when using arrow notation

Tags: javascript, meteor, flow-router

I'm implementing some routing groups, based on [post I found](https://medium.com/@satyavh/using-flow-router-for-authentication-ba7bb2644f42#.s0qqmf7qu) which uses arrow notation.

I'm using the latest version of meteor and all top level dependencies are up to date too.

When I save my routes.js, I get an unexpected token error which fails on the arrow notation in the code. I'm missing something obvious I'm sure, any clues?

```
loggedIn = FlowRouter.group
  triggersEnter: [ ->
    unless Meteor.loggingIn() or Meteor.userId()
      route = FlowRouter.current()
      unless route.route.name is 'login'
        Session.set 'redirectAfterLogin', route.path
      FlowRouter.go ‘loginLayout’
  ]
```

Error:

> While building for web.browser:
>   imports/startup/client/routes.js:10:18: Unexpected token (10:18)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial is in coffeescript not js and you are loading it in a .js file which should be .coffee however if you have other js code in routes.js then you need to convert coffee to js. The snippet above would become:

```
var loggedIn = FlowRouter.group({ 
    triggersEnter: [ function() { 
        var route; 
        if (!(Meteor.loggingIn() || Meteor.userId())) { 
            route = FlowRouter.current(); 
            if (route.route.name !== 'login') { 
                Session.set('redirectAfterLogin', route.path); 
            } 
            return FlowRouter.go(‘loginLayout’); 
        } 
    }] 
});
```

Comment: cant believe i didnt spot that it was coffeescript. it was a long day haha. thanks!